# Auto Saving a Google Search Result Page

Tags: google-search

I was trying to auto save a Google result page but when I opened the designated folder and clicked on the autosave file, it won't open the Google result page. There was a message that said `Some pictures have been blocked to help prevent the sender from identifying your computer.`

Why can't I open the file? What should I do?

Comment: did you save this to your computer? And what do you mean by `auto save`?

Answer (score 0):

If you `view source` and save you will not necessarily be able to reproduce the page via the saved HTML source; if you `save as` anything else you may encounter formatting difficulties (such as you described).

My advice is to save as a PDF, either by `print - print preview - save as pdf`, or by an online [service](http://pdfcrowd.com) that converts an URL to a PDF (pdfcrowd.com also has a Firefox extension).  Alternately, you could take a snapshot of the page, or even possibly explore sites such as [view web page as googlebot](http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/index.htm) or lmgtfy.com (let me google that for you).